# Dynamically split div columns

Tags: javascript, php, html, while-loop

code i have written below is working fine but at the end of the looping the div is not closed its still opening a loop

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
       <div class="row">
        <?php 
        $recent_projects_sql="SELECT * from recent_projects where service_type='upholstery'";   
        $recent_projects_conn=mysql_query($recent_projects_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
        $i=0; $split=0;

        while($projects=mysql_fetch_array($recent_projects_conn)) {   
             $i++; 
             ?>
             <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-item" style="">
                    <div class="photo-shadow"></div>
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="admin/assets/images/uploads/projects/<?php echo $projects['attachment1']; ?>" alt="User one">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="name">
                            <?php echo $projects['service_name']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="degination">
                            <?php echo $projects['sub_title']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <a class="btn btn-theme ripple-effect" href="#">View More</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php 
            $split++;   
            if ($split % 4 == 0){  
               echo '</div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">';  
            }   
       }
       ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Div has splited very well but in end of the loop div has not been closed. Thats only the problem please provide me the help to sort out the problem

When I inspect the element the last loop will show at the given result as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="col-item">
        <div class="photo-shadow"></div>
        <div class="photo">
            <img src="admin/assets/images/uploads/projects/1557301934.jpg" alt="User one">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="name">UPHOLSTERY</div>
            <div class="degination">UPHOLSTERY</div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a class="btn btn-theme ripple-effect" href="#">View More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">
```

I want to remove the two opening div's as  dynamically. How can i set this to remove opened div's at then end of the looping

Comment: Why you don't add if clause at the beginning of while, and exclude first occurence?

Comment: From 2nd rows itself i want to split the rows that's y i add if class... If it's wrong means i will proceed it your way to solve

Comment: Just adding if clause at the top and changing it to `if ($split && !($split % 4)) {}` would resolve it. Otherwise you would need to know exact count of rows (if next row exists).

Comment: You can also use `ob_start` and `ob_get_flush` at the beggining of while script, but I don't find it nessecary to complicate.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php 
$recent_projects_sql="SELECT * from recent_projects where service_type='upholstery'";   
$recent_projects_conn=mysql_query($recent_projects_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
$i=0; $split=0;

while($projects=mysql_fetch_array($recent_projects_conn)) {   
     $i++; 
?>
    <div class="item <?php if($i==1) echo "active";?>">
       <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-item" style="">
                    <div class="photo-shadow"></div>
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="admin/assets/images/uploads/projects/<?php echo $projects['attachment1']; ?>" alt="User one">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="name">
                            <?php echo $projects['service_name']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="degination">
                            <?php echo $projects['sub_title']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <a class="btn btn-theme ripple-effect" href="#">View More</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: shows only one image in a row but in static it has 4 images